# Zend Framework + Tricky controller name and module name conflict

Tags: zend-framework

We have a Zend application that has these following modules:

```
Users
Shop
etc...
Front - A content management module
```

While the Front module has the following controllers:

```
UsersController
ShopController
AuthController
etc...
```

In the middle of our development cycle we decided to set the default module for the Zend application to the Front module, but inadvertently broke our links, as http://domain.com/front/users/list are now generated as http://domain.com/users/list, which is now pointing to the wrong action.

We are generating links using the URL view helper, (i.e. `$this->url(array('module' => 'front', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'list'));`), but the 'front' URI segment is omitted since switching the default module to the Front module.

I totally understand why this is so, but we are avoiding renaming all controllers under the Front module to avoid conflicts.

My question is, is there is a way to instruct the URL view helper to *always* include the 'front' module URI segment even if it is already set as the default one?

Comment: Might need to add custom routes, at least for the front module. Then your call to the url view-helper changes to something like `$this->url(array(), 'front-user-list')`. A pain to be sure - adding routes and changing the `url()` invocations - but it will work as a fallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, is there is a way to instruct the URL view helper to
>   always include the 'front' module URI segment even if it is already
>   set as the default one?

You can create your own url view helper with same name and override default url view helper add it to Zend_View object in your bootstrap.

```
   $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
    if (null === $viewRenderer->view) 
    {
        $viewRenderer->initView();
    }

    $view = $viewRenderer->view;

    $view->addHelperPath('/path/to/some/helpers', 'My_View_Helper');
```

Now create class My_View_Helper_Url let it extend Zend_View_Helper_Url override url method.
Here is reference form ZF doc about this procedure

> In fact, you can "stack" paths using the addHelperPath() method. As
>   you add paths to the stack, Zend_View will look at the
>   most-recently-added path for the requested helper class. This allows
>   you to add to (or even override) the initial distribution of helpers
>   with your own custom helpers.

Having said that I think http://domain.com/users/list, should have worked correctly in first place since you have specified default module to front.

Comment: Will try this out. Thanks. PS. http://domain.com/users/list wouldn't map to the `Front_UsersController::listAction`. Instead, it tries to map to a non-existent `Users_ListController::indexAction`.